# JavaFX, resizeable container, beside a non-resizeable container

Tags: java, javafx, vbox, hbox

I want a couple things to be on the screen, but I am not quite sure which layout system I should use.

From the right side of the screen I want a container, 300px wide and screen height.

The left container will just fill out the rest of the screen, after the right container has taken its position.

So a big container, that has resize priority, and then another container 300px wide.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: containme]

**Sample Code to Produce the Layout Pictured Above**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Creates a full screen display with two containers.
 * The right container is fixed to 300 pixels wide.
 * The left container fills the remaining available space.
 */
public class ContainerSample extends Application {
    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // create a resizable pane.
        final StackPane left = new StackPane();
        left.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue;");
        left.setPrefWidth(500);

        // create a pane with a 300 pixel fixed width.
        final StackPane right = new StackPane();
        right.setStyle("-fx-background-color: palegreen;");
        right.setPrefWidth(300);
        right.setMinWidth(StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        right.setMaxWidth(StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        // layout the left and right pane.
        final HBox layout = new HBox(left, right);

        // grow the left pane width to fill available space.
        HBox.setHgrow(left, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // exit the application on mouse click.
        layout.setOnMouseClicked(event -> stage.hide());

        // uncomment to disallow exiting the full screen mode.
        //stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
        //stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);

        // display the main application screen in full screen mode.
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My way of doing this was waay more complicated then it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

Or in FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <AnchorPane prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: palegreen;" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```